# How to convert Log file to CSV using bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, logs

Is it possible to turn this log entry into a properly formatted csv file using sed/awk?
I've tried multiple ways to do this using sed/awk. Alas I couldn't do it. Before I do it in perl. is this possible in AWK/sed or perhaps even bash

```
Jan 21 11:10:45 hostname.internal.nl THREAT 2015/01/21 11:10:44 critical 5 reset-both outside 10.10.10.10 inside 10.16.61.4 tcp 39898 80 web-browsing any Bash Remote Code Execution Vulnerability(36731)
```

Like this

```
Date  | Hostname | Threat | DATE+time | Critical/High | Count | --- | External IP | Internal IP | TCP/UDP | Port | External Port| Category | Vulnerability 

Jan 21 11:10:45 | hostname.internal.nl | THREAT | 2015/01/21 11:10:44 | critical 5 reset-both | outside 10.10.10.10 | inside 10.16.61.4 | tcp  39898 | 80 | web-browsing | 4any Bash Remote Code Execution Vulnerability(36731)
```

Comment: What method did you try?

Comment: What do you mean by `bash`? Yes, it is possible, but it is a very bad idea. Tools like perl, awk or sed are much better for this sort of thing. What do you have against them? Also, how are fields defined? Is `critical 5 reset-bot` one field or three and, if one, how would bash be able to tell?

Comment: You have logged into a different account. Try merging in your old account.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can do it in bash but I have no idea why you would want to. Here's a pure bash solution:

```
$ while read -r mon day time host threat date time crit count sugg out exip \
                in inip tcp port export cat vuln; do 
     printf "%s | " "$mon $day $time" "$host" "$threat" "$date $time" \ 
                    "$crit $count $sugg" "$out $exip" "$in $inip" "$tcp \
                    $port" "$export" "$cat" "$vuln"
  done < file; printf "\n"
Jan 21 11:10:44 | hostname.internal.nl | THREAT | 2015/01/21 11:10:44 | critical 5 reset-both | outside 10.10.10.10 | inside 10.16.61.4 | tcp 39898 | 80 | web-browsing | any Bash Remote Code Execution Vulnerability(36731) |
```

I could give you better ways in perl or awk but they will depend on how exactly you define your fields. If you update your question with more details (for example, will there always be 3 words in the critical field? We need to know what will always be the same in your input and what can change), I can give you a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your input lines are the same type, you can do like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG="/root/1.txt"

echo "Date | Hostname | Threat | DATE+time | Critical/High | Count | --- | External IP | Internal IP | TCP/UDP | Port | External Port | Category | Vulnerability" > 1.csv

< $LOG awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3 " | " $4 " | " $5 " | " $6" "$7 " | " $8" "$9" "$10 " | " $11" "$12 " | " $13" "$14 " | " $15" "$16 " | " $17 " | " $18 " | " $19" "$20" "$21" "$22" "$23" "$24}' >> 1.csv
```

Input:

```
Jan 21 11:10:45 hostname.internal.nl THREAT 2015/01/21 11:10:44 critical 5 reset-both outside 10.10.10.10 inside 10.16.61.4 tcp 39898 80 web-browsing any Bash Remote Code Execution Vulnerability(36731)

Jan 22 11:12:45 hostname2.internal.nl THREAT2 2015/01/22 12:10:44 critical2 52 reset-both2 outside2 10.10.10.12 inside2 10.16.61.42 udp 39899 82 web-browsing2 any2 Bash Remote Code Execution Vulnerability(36731)2
```

Output:

```
Date | Hostname | Threat | DATE+time | Critical/High | Count | --- | External IP | Internal IP | TCP/UDP | Port | External Port | Category | Vulnerability
Jan 21 11:10:45 | hostname.internal.nl | THREAT | 2015/01/21 11:10:44 | critical 5 reset-both | outside 10.10.10.10 | inside 10.16.61.4 | tcp 39898 | 80 | web-browsing | any Bash Remote Code Execution Vulnerability(36731)
Jan 22 11:12:45 | hostname2.internal.nl | THREAT2 | 2015/01/22 12:10:44 | critical2 52 reset-both2 | outside2 10.10.10.12 | inside2 10.16.61.42 | udp 39899 | 82 | web-browsing2 | any2 Bash Remote Code Execution Vulnerability(36731)2
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this very useful for collecting log files from S3 Cloudfront and loading them into Google Drive.

I used awscli on Mac-Os after installing this with homebrew awscli. 
I ran the command :

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucketname/domain/ .
```

The bucket was filled with cloudfront logs (I turn this on at the cloudfront edit) and all the files where pulled to my local computer. I ran unzipped on the .gz files and got text files.

After this at the same folder I used the find + exec command to build one big log file as described below. After that I broke down the log into the cloudfront log format and generated a CSV file using commas as a split at the awk. This CSV was uploaded to Google drive for some pivot analysis and helped me to find bad edges and missing files.

This is the bash script I used for this :

```
`#!bash/bin
#Join Logs into one Big File using cat , if there are any default  headers on your files . you need to remove them
FILE_NAMES_START = 'E1I*'
find . -type f -name FILE_NAMES_START -exec cat {} + >> big_log_file.txt
#Output Log File 
LOG="big_log_file.txt"
echo "DATE , TIME , X-Edge-Location , SC-Bytes , Client-IP , Method , Cs-Host , File-URI , HTTP Status , Referer , User Agent , URI Query , Cookie-Id , Edge-Result , Edge-Request-ID , Host Header , Protocol , Bytes , Time Taken , X-Forwader , SSL Protocol , SSL Cipher , CDN-Result-Type" >> csv_data.csv
< $LOG awk '{print $1 " ,  " $2" ,  " $3 " , " $4 " , " $5 " , " $6 " , " $7 " , " $8 " , " $9 " , " $10 " , " $11 " , " $12 " , " $13 " , " $14 " , " $15 " , " $16 " , " $17 " , " $18 " , " $19 " , " $20 " , " $21 " , " $22 " , " $23 " , " $24}' >> big_csv_file.csv`
```

Make sure txt files and this bash code are at the same library or add needed / to the script.

csv > 100Mb doesn't work so well on Google sheets.